# How to pre-select radio button on load (Express / NodeJS / EJS)?

Tags: html, node.js, radio-button, ejs

How do you preselect a radio button using Express / NodeJS / EJS?

Backend / Express:

```
user = {
   likeCats: false
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>Do you like cats?</p>

<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="likeCats" id="catsYes" value=true> Yes
  <input type="radio" name="likeCats" id="catsNo" value=false> No
</form>
```

I have tried DOM manipulation, but it won't work, e.g.

Clientside JS:

```
//user is obviously undefined in the clientside, so this fails.
if(user.likeCats){   
    document.getElementById('catsYes').checked = true;
}
```

Comment: I think you are mixing up client side and backend programming. You can not directly refer to a variable in NodeJS from the client side HTML code.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution would be

```
if(true){
   <input type="radio" name="likeCats" id="catsYes" checked>
}
else{
   <input type="radio" name="likeCats" id="catsYes">
}
```

A better way of doing this :

```
<input type="radio" name="likeCats" id="catsYes" 
    <%if(true){%>
        <%="checked"%>
    <%}%>
>
```

Comment: Wow... seems superfluous, especially if you have more than two options... but this will work. TY. Wonder what other answers I can get...

Answer (score 3):

You can use ternary operator for a simple and clean code, especially for big number of options.

```
<input type="radio" name="likeCats" id="catsYes" <%= user.likeCats ? 'checked' : '' %> >
```